# PHP DOM simple parser get values from td

Tags: php, html, parsing, domparser

i'm having some troubles using Dom simple parser, I would like to get some values from a table in a html file, i want only values in td that has id='ok'.

I mean:

```
<tr>
     <td id="no"> 18 </td>
     <td id="yes"> 19 </td>
     <td id="maybe"> 20 </td>
     <td id="ok"> 21 </td>    ---- i only want this value
<tr>

<tr>
     <td id="no"> 18 </td>
     <td id="yes"> 19 </td>
     <td id="maybe"> 20 </td>
     <td id="no"> 25 </td>
<tr>
```

i'm trying to use this code:

```
$ret = $html->find('td[id='ok']');
```

but it seems it doesn't work. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should. Here's a different selector.
Both worked for me.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('test.html');
$elem = $html->find('td#ok', 0);
echo $elem->plaintext;
```

Note: find() returns an array unless the 2nd parameter (index) is specified

Comment: Great, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1):

One more solution (*without third-party parsers*) is to use `DOMDocument` and `XPATH`

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Making validator to be less strict (bec. invalid XML structure will cause parsing failure)
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
// Reading HTML directly in argument (saving one line of code)
$doc->loadHTML( file_get_contents('/some/test.html') );

$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
// Applying XPATH on parsed document
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//*[@id='ok']")
```